# Как правильно вывести data-атрибуты в модальном окне bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap

Есть две ссылки вида:

```
<a href="#popup-zakaz-form" class="btn btn-line dark btn-xs popup-contact" data-bname="Букет «Весна»" data-bimg="images/buket/2.jpg" data-bprice="580" >Заказ</a>

<a href="#popup-zakaz-form" class="btn btn-line dark btn-xs popup-contact" data-bname="Букет «Лето»" data-bimg="images/buket/3.jpg" data-bprice="280" >Заказ</a>
```

При клике на них открывается всплывающее окно заказа. Окно открывается и все работает, вопрос заключается в том, чтоб не клонировать кучу окон с параметрами для каждого товара, а сделать при этом одну форму всплывающего окна, а необходимые параметры передать в дата-атрибутах и выводить их с помощью jquery. Сделал форму, но почему-то ничего не работает:
Код самого окна:

```
<!-- Popup contact form -->
  <div id="popup-zakaz-form" class="white-popup-block popup-form mfp-hide">
    <div class="pop-header">
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
      <h3 class="title medium">ОФОРМИТЬ ЗАКАЗ</h3>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="blc">y</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="pop-body">
          <form action="form-data/formdata.php" class="form-widget" data-popup="popup-contact">
            <input type="hidden" name="to" value="r.genesis.art@gmail.com">
            <input class="form-control" data-label="Name" required data-msg="Пожалуйста, введите ваше имя." type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
            <input class="form-control"  data-label="Phone" required data-msg="Пожалуйста, введите ваш номер телефона." type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> ЗАКАЗАТЬ</button>
          </form>   
          <div class="msg-block"></div>
        </div>

    <script>
    var bimg = $('a').data('bimg');
    var bname = $('a').data('bname');
    var bprice = $('a').data('bprice');

    $( '#blc' ).html( '<div class="img"><img style="width: 100%;" src="'+ bimg +'" alt="оформление заказа"></div><h3 class="hd"> ' + bname + ' </h3>' );
    </script>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /#popup-contact-form -->
```

Подозреваю, что не правильно оформил ява код, помогите, пожалуйста с решением данного вопроса!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(
    function() {
      var bname = $(this).attr('data-bname');
      var bimg = $(this).attr('data-bimg');
      var bprice = $(this).attr('data-bprice');

      $(".kartka").append('<h1>' + bname + '</h1>');
      $(".kartka").append('<img src="' + bimg + '" alt="" />');
      $(".kartka").append('<p>' + bprice + '</p>');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#popup-zakaz-form" class="btn btn-line dark btn-xs popup-contact" data-bname="Букет «Весна»" data-bimg="images/buket/2.jpg" data-bprice="580">Заказ</a>

<div class="kartka"></div>
```

или такой вариант

```js
   $(function() {
     $(".btn").click(
       function() {
         var bname = $(this).attr('data-bname');
         var bimg = $(this).attr('data-bimg');
         var bprice = $(this).attr('data-bprice');

         $(".kartka h1").text(bname);
         $(".kartka img").attr('src', bimg);
         $(".kartka p").html(bprice);
       })
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#popup-zakaz-form" class="btn btn-line dark btn-xs popup-contact" data-bname="Букет «Весна»" data-bimg="images/buket/2.jpg" data-bprice="580">Заказ</a>

<div class="kartka">
  <h1></h1>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <p></p>
</div>
```